# Combine two regex

Tags: jquery, regex, jquery-validate

I'm using jquery.validationengine.en.js to (custom )validate my form fields. For one field, I'm using two custom validation. I don't want to display both the validation message for a field. It should display only one msg at a time. How to do that?

Please find the code below
Note: allzero is used by some other fields too.

```
   "phone":   {
                  "regex": /^[0-9]{8,15}$/,
                  "alertText": "* Invalid phone number"
              },
   "allzero": {
                  "regex": /([^((\+)*(0*))])/,
                  "alertText": "* Invalid number"
              },
```

HTML code:

```
<input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" class="textBox textNormal validate[maxSize[30],custom[onlyNumberSp],custom[phonenumber],custom[allzero]]" onfocus="jQuery('#adduserform').validationEngine('attach',{Overflown:false})">

    <input type="text" name="mobile" id="mobile" class="textBox textNormal validate[maxSize[30],custom[onlyNumberSp],custom[mobile],custom[allzero]]" value="" onfocus="jQuery('#adduserform').validationEngine('attach',{Overflown:false})">
```

Comment: Can you show some code? Specifically, the definition of the two validation rules?

Comment: Added code. Please check

Comment: If your first regex only allows numbers, why does the second appear to permit an arbitrary number of leading  plus signs? Anyway, the second regex is badly borked - presumably you mean something like `/^\+?0*$/`?

Comment: I'm using allzero for some other fields too which will accept + sign once. So, I used in that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the validation engine usage instructions (at https://github.com/posabsolute/jQuery-Validation-Engine), it seems it's possible to validate a field using a custom function call (the `funcCall` validator). So, you should be able to use a function to check both regexps one after another, and return the appropriate error message if one of them doesn't match:

```
function checkPhoneNumber(field, rules, i, options){
    if (!field.val().match(/^[0-9]{8,15}$/))
        return "* Invalid phone number";
    else if (!field.val().match(/([^((\+)*(0*))])/))
        return "* Invalid number";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

One way would be to always require a non-zero digit somewhere in the string. This can be done by the regex part `[0-9]*[1-9][0-9]*`. However, you then lose the ability to easily check the string length. This can be overcome by a lookahead assertion resulting in the following regex:

```
/^(?=[0-9]{8,15}$)[0-9]*[1-9][0-9]*$/
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I could do it when using a function:

```
        "phoneORallzero": { 
            "func": function(field, rules, i, options){
                if (field.val().match(/^[0-9]{8,15}$/))
                    return true;
                else if (field.val().match(/([^((\+)*(0*))])/))
                    return true;
            },
            "alertText": "* invalid phone or number."
        }
```

In the HTML code:

```
... class = "validate[custom[phoneORallzero]]" ...
```